# How can I run a command or script in rosetta from terminal on M1 Mac?

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, terminal, zsh

How can I run a program or shell script in Rosetta from Terminal? I don't want to run the whole terminal in Rosetta. Just the parts I need.

Answer (score 10):

The `arch` command is useful for that purpose

```
arch -arch_name binary args ...
```

See `man arch` for more details

**Example without rosetta:**

```
echo "arch" > build.sh
arch -arm64 /bin/bash ./build.sh
```

Output:

```
arm64
```

(could run this with `/bin/bash ./build.sh` directly)

**Example with rosetta:**

```
echo "arch" > build.sh
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash ./build.sh
```

Output:

```
i386
```